# "cannot find module lodash" when trying API - Platform 's react generator

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm trying to generate a front-end for my symfony app building with API - platform follow the documentation on this page:

https://api-platform.com/docs/client-generator/react/

However, this does not seem to work. I received "cannot find module lodash" when ran this command,

`$ npx @api-platform/client-generator https://demo.api-platform.com src/ --resource book`

I have also tried with API Platform distribution (as advised in the documentation) but it does not work. I received the same error message regarding "lodash" module.

Any advice would be appreciated.